# How to horizontally align rows to two matrices when entries have different heights in latex?

Tags: latex

I'm new to latex so forgive me if this is basic, but I can't figure out how to horizontally align rows of two side-by-side matrices where the entries in one take up more vertical space.

Here is the code I have

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
W_0\\
\vdots\\
W_{\frac{L}{2}}\\
\vdots\\
W_{\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{4}}\\
\vdots\\
W_{\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{4}+\frac{L}{8}}\\
\vdots\\
W_{L-2}\\
W_{L-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x_1-x_0)\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{2} \big ( \sum\limits_{\ell^=2}^3 x_\ell - \sum\limits_{\ell=0}^1 x_\ell \big ) \\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \big ( \sum_{\ell=4}^7 x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^3 x_\ell \big )\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{8} \big ( \sum_{\ell=8}^{15} x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^7 x_\ell \big )\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \big ( \sum_{\ell=\frac{L}{2}}^{L-1} x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^{\frac{L}{2}-1} x_\ell \big )\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \sum_{\ell=0}^{L-1} x_\ell
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

You can see I have the same number of entries in each column vector, but the corresponding entries are not aligned due to the entries of the right hand vector being taller. How can I make the entries in each vector align horizontally?

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<height>}` command

```
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8} % Here
\begin{bmatrix}
W_0\\
\vdots\\
W_{\frac{L}{2}}\\
\vdots\\
W_{\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{4}}\\
\vdots\\
W_{\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{4}+\frac{L}{8}}\\
\vdots\\
W_{L-2}\\
W_{L-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x_1-x_0)\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{2} \big ( \sum\limits_{\ell^=2}^3 x_\ell - \sum\limits_{\ell=0}^1 x_\ell \big ) \\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \big ( \sum_{\ell=4}^7 x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^3 x_\ell \big )\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{8} \big ( \sum_{\ell=8}^{15} x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^7 x_\ell \big )\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \big ( \sum_{\ell=\frac{L}{2}}^{L-1} x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^{\frac{L}{2}-1} x_\ell \big )\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \sum_{\ell=0}^{L-1} x_\ell
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
```

[image: Corrected output]

The less-efficient but custom way:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
\vspace{0.2em}W_0\\
\vspace{0.175em}\vdots\\
\vspace{0.225em}W_{\frac{L}{2}}\\
\vspace{0.3em}\vdots\\
\vspace{0.2em}W_{\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{4}}\\
\vspace{0.2em}\vdots\\
\vspace{0.2em}W_{\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L}{4}+\frac{L}{8}}\\
\vspace{0.2em}\vdots\\
\vspace{0.2em}W_{L-2}\\
\vspace{0.3em}W_{L-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x_1-x_0)\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{2} \big ( \sum\limits_{\ell^=2}^3 x_\ell - \sum\limits_{\ell=0}^1 x_\ell \big ) \\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \big ( \sum_{\ell=4}^7 x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^3 x_\ell \big )\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{8} \big ( \sum_{\ell=8}^{15} x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^7 x_\ell \big )\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \big ( \sum_{\ell=\frac{L}{2}}^{L-1} x_\ell -  \sum_{\ell=0}^{\frac{L}{2}-1} x_\ell \big )\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \sum_{\ell=0}^{L-1} x_\ell
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
```

[image: Corrected output]